# How to convert MD5 with BigInt MD5 Hash to String format in NodeJs with equivalent code from Java

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, typescript

I have the following code in Java for `MD5` hash. I want to convert into in equivalent NodeJs with Typescript.

Code in Java

```
String secretKey = "MyID~Denmark";
final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")       final byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes());
final BigInteger number = new BigInteger(messageDigest);
String value = String.format("%032x", number);
System.out.println("Value: "+value);
```

I have also tried in the following Typescript code, the results from Java and NodeJs are not equal.

```
public checkMd51(): void {
        const country: string = "Denmark";
        const projectId: string = "MyID";
        const secretKey: string = projectId + "~" + country;
        // const key: string = crypto.createHash("md5").update(String(secretKey)).digest();

        const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(secretKey).digest('hex');

        const bigInt = BigInt(`0x${md5.substring(0, 32)}`);
        // const bigInt = BigInt(`0x${md5}`);
        // const val1 = util.format('%s:%s:%s', bigInt);

        console.log("MD5 value: ", val1.toString());

        
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. The following code is the equivalent of what you have written for MD5 digest in java.

```
const country: string = "Denmark";
const projectId: string = "MyID";
const secretKey: string = projectId + "~" + country;
const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(secretKey).digest('hex');
console.log("MD5: ", md5);
```

Run both java program and the above code with Typescript and NodeJs and you can verify that both are equal.